# Xorg conf not loading on startup

Tags: xorg

I have an Xorg conf to fix my mouse. Without it my mouse does not work. When I start my system and get past the login my mouse works momentarily (it did that before anyway) and it stops. I need to open terminal and kill Xorg `sudo killall Xorg`, re-login and my mouse is fixed.

Is there a fix to get the Xorg conf to load properly without having to kill Xorg?

Manjaro 4.4.13-1, xorg-server 1.17.4-2, Mad Catz R.A.T.7, KDE KDM

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-vmmouse.conf**

```
Section "InputDevice"
  Identifier "Mouse0"
  Driver     "evdev"
  Option     "Name" "Mad Catz Mad Catz R.A.T.7 Mouse"
  Option     "Vendor" "06a3"
  Option     "Product" "0ccc"
  Option     "Protocol" "auto"
  Option     "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
  Option     "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
  Option     "Buttons" "7"
  Option     "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
  Option     "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
  Option     "Resolution" "3200"
EndSection
```

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](http://pastebin.com/kV3QuWMs)

Comment: This may or may not be relevant to your problem, but it's worth trying.  Most gaming mice and keyboards these days register as both a keyboard and a mouse, so that they can play tricks with macros.  For this reason, it's a good idea to tie the pointer and the keyboard sections to the right USB IDs, or to the right physical port.  Something like this: `Option "Phys" "usb-0000:00:14.0-10.2/input0"`.  This way your mouse won't take over the "main" keyboard, nor the keyboard would take over the "main" mouse.

Comment: What configuration did you make? Copy-paste the relevant file names and content. How does X start — what display manager do you use?

Comment: X11 logs (typically `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`) should also provide information about what's going on.